# ClassCastException: java.lang.Object incompatible with com.company.base.BaseDocument

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that has to be JDK 1.4 compliant. And below is a snippet which gets a runtime exception.

```
BaseDocument baseDocument = new BaseDocument();
baseDocument.setGuid("{somethinghere}");
List document = new ArrayList();
document.add(baseDocument);//runtime error
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with [Lcom.company.base.BaseDocument;
```

I don't understand why we cant cast it to a java Object(since Object is the parent class of all Classes in java).

Im using IBM JDK version 1.7 with Eclipse compiler settings set to JDK 1.4

Please explain what mistake I'm doing here. I know generics is the standard, but it has to be JDK 1.4 compliant :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace to your question. From the look of it, the code you're presenting shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: That is the complete trace. I dont know why it is so, but i have set the compiler level in eclipse to correspond to JDK 1.4 and also in the project properties.

Comment: @user1994694 - That is not a complete trace.  It is just the exception message.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the message says:

```
 [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with [Lcom.company.base.BaseDocument;
```

The `[` characters are very important.  Apparently, something is attempting cast something of type `Object[]` to `BaseDocument[]`; i.e. you are dealing with array types here.

However, I have no idea what is actually causing the problem here, because (on the face of it) there should be no instances of `BaseDocument[]` in the code you have posted.  Furthermore, I don't believe your claim that that exception is thrown at that line.  Here is the source code of the `ArrayList.add` method (Java 6 version):

```
 private transient Object[] elementData;

 public boolean add(E e) {
     ensureCapacity(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
     elementData[size++] = e;
     return true;
 }
```

An assignment of a reference into an object array (`Object[]`) does not entail any runtime type-checks, and cannot throw a `ClassCastException`.

If you showed us a *complete* stacktrace, it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: Yes it was actually not at that point in code but the next line where as you said im trying to cast an Object[] to a BaseDocument[]. I cant believe I became too comfortable with generics that I overlooked this. Was a mistake with the sysout location. Thanks a lot Stephen !! :)

Comment: But im still not sure why i didnt get a full stack trace as usual(what I gave as the Exception is all that i got in Eclipse console! No red stack trace text at all!). Can it be because of a bug with eclipse/IBM JDK, where setting compiler compliance level to 1.4 from 1.7 actually causes this problem?